# Sort & Parallelism costing my query too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL query is taking a large amount of time to run. I wrote a similar query and pit them against each other and this one runs FASTER when a small dataset (10K lines) is used, but about 20-30x slower than the other one when a LARGE dataset (500K+ lines) is used. My first query however does not have ONE column that I need, and I **cannot** add it without going about it with this different approach.

```
SELECT a.[RFIDTAGID], a.[JOB_NUMBER], d.[PROJECT_NUMBER], a.[PART_NUMBER], a.[QUANTITY], b.[DESIGNATION] as LOCATION, 
c.[DESIGNATION] as CONTAINER, a.[LAST_SEEN_TIME], b.[TYPE], b.[BLDG], d.[PBG], d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE], d.[EXTENSION_DATE], a.[ORG_ID]
FROM [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_PACKAGE] as a

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT [DESIGNATION], [CONTAINER_ID], [LOCATION_ID]
    FROM [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_CONTAINER]
    ) c ON a.[CONTAINER_ID] = c.[CONTAINER_ID]

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT [DESIGNATION], [TYPE], [BLDG], [LOCATION_ID]
    FROM [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_LOCATION]
    ) b ON a.[LAST_SEEN_LOC_ID] = b.[LOCATION_ID] OR b.[LOCATION_ID] = c.[LOCATION_ID]

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [PBG], [PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE], [EXTENSION_DATE], [DISCRETE_JOB_NUMBER], [PROJECT_NUMBER]
    FROM [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY]
)d ON a.[JOB_NUMBER] = d.[DISCRETE_JOB_NUMBER]

WHERE
d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE] <= GETDATE()
AND b.[TYPE] NOT IN('MFG', 'Manufacturing')
AND (b.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL OR c.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL)

ORDER BY [JOB_NUMBER], d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE] desc,  [RFIDTAGID];
```

You can see below the usage, 100% is roughly 20,000, whereas my other query is about 900:
[image]

Is there something I can do to speed up my query, or where did I bog it down?

Comment: Stop using inner selects

Answer (score 0):

Remove inner selects and join directly to the tables:

```
  SELECT a.[RFIDTAGID], a.[JOB_NUMBER], d.[PROJECT_NUMBER], a.[PART_NUMBER], a.[QUANTITY], b.[DESIGNATION] as LOCATION, 
    c.[DESIGNATION] as CONTAINER, a.[LAST_SEEN_TIME], b.[TYPE], b.[BLDG], d.[PBG], d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE], d.[EXTENSION_DATE], a.[ORG_ID]
    FROM [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_PACKAGE] a

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_CONTAINER]
       c ON a.[CONTAINER_ID] = c.[CONTAINER_ID]

    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LTS_LOCATION]
          b ON a.[LAST_SEEN_LOC_ID] = b.[LOCATION_ID] OR b.[LOCATION_ID] = c.[LOCATION_ID]

    INNER JOIN  
     [LTS].[dbo].[LTS_DISCRETE_JOB_SUMMARY]
     d ON a.[JOB_NUMBER] = d.[DISCRETE_JOB_NUMBER]

    WHERE
    d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE] <= GETDATE()
    AND b.[TYPE] NOT IN('MFG', 'Manufacturing')
    AND (b.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL OR c.[DESIGNATION] IS NOT NULL)

    ORDER BY [JOB_NUMBER], d.[PLANNED_MFG_DELIVERY_DATE] desc,  [RFIDTAGID];
```

Comment: Also the join to [dbo].[LTS_LOCATION] on an 'or' will slow you down

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried joining directly to the tables and it doesn't seem to improve my runtime at all.

Comment: get rid of your 'ors' one on join one in where clause